# I am not able to change the status of a "Tables column". column name of Table is 'number'. which is matching to my input 'table' in my controller

Tags: sql, database, laravel, multiple-columns, shopping-cart

```
public function complete(Request $request, $id){
    $order = Order::find($id);

    // Update the Order
    $value =  $request->input('table');
    $number = DB::table('tables')->where('number' , '=' , $value)->update(['status' => "Fine"]);
    $order->update(['status' => 'CompletedOrders']);


    return redirect()->route('servedorders');
}
```

I assigned a variable to my table input. and then i am trying to match this variable to the column in Tables table. But i am not able to update the value to "Free". Is there anything wrong with my query?

The view from where all the value are coming.

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
                @if($order->status == "OrdersServed")
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul class="list-group" >

                                <li class="list-group-item" style="background-color: #467aeb">
                                    <a href="{{route('showcompleteorder',$order->id)}}"><h1 style="color: #051942; font-family: Helvetica; font-weight: bold">Order# {{$order->id}}</h1></a>
                                    <span class="label label-success"><p style="font-size: 15px; color: white">Name: <b>{{$order->name}}</b></p></span>
                                    <span class="label label-success"><p style="font-size: 15px; color: white">Phone: <b>{{$order->phone}}</b></p></span>
                                    @foreach($order->cart->items as $item)
                                        <span class="label label-success"><p style="font-size: 15px; color: #051942"><b>{{$item['qty'] }} {{ $item['item']['name'] }} </b></p></span>
                                        <span class="label label-success"><p style="font-size: 15px; color: #051942">Price: <b>₹{{ $item['price'] }}</b></p></span>
                                    @endforeach
                                    <span class="label label-success"><p style="font-size: 15px; color: white">Table: <b>{{$order->table}}</b></p></span>
                                    <br>
                                    <span class="badge" style="color: #051942; font-size: 16px">Order Time: {{$order->created_at}}</span>
                                    <br>
                                    @if($order->status == 'OrdersServed')
                                        <a class="btn btn-block btn-info btn-flat" style="font-size: 20px" href="{{route('complete', $order->id)}}">Order Completed</a>
                                @endif
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if `$value` contains any value, then see if the `where` condition is true.

Comment: i tried to echo $value. Nothing showed. It's not getting the value. what should i do?

Comment: Post the view that contains `table`

Comment: i posted it. Please have a look.

Comment: how can i get value of table in $value.

Answer (score 0):

Your view does not contain `<input>` to send with the `$request` to `complete` function, So `$request->input('table')` is returning empty values.

But i can see your `order` does contain `table`, And you're sending the order `id` to the `complete` function so use that:

```
 $order = Order::find($id);

// Update the Order
$number = DB::table('tables')->where('number' , '=' , $order->table)->update(['status' => "Fine"]);
$order->update(['status' => 'CompletedOrders']);
```